# How to change video source through selecting link - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I'm trying to change the source of a video from selecting a link. So when the link is selected on the page, it will change the video overhead to the source of another video, sort of like a playlist.
This is the code for my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/    DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Videos</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="VideosPage.css">


<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

<video id="first_video" width="800" height="450" controls="controls" style="margin-left:380px;  padding:10px; border:1px solid black;">

<source src="video.mp4" type="video.mp4" />

</video>

 <br />


  <a> Other Video  </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the HTML standard:
http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#video.

There's a couple of solutions you could use. One is loading the next video sequentially, like a playlist:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var nextVideo = "path/of/next/video.mp4";
var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('video');
videoPlayer.onend = function(){
    videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
}
</script>
<video id="videoPlayer" src="path/of/current/video.mp4" autoplay autobuffer controls />
```

Then, making a link to change it would be as simple as (for example):

```
$("a.change_link").click(function(){
    videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
});
```

Comment: I'm very new to javascript, so my understanding of the code is very vague. If I wanted to implement this code to my html and have it work with my own html, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: I've updated my code. Basically change the paths to the real location of your videos.

Comment: Then I just add the link to change the source, and does this link take the id"change_link", or how does the link tie into to the javascript

Comment: Yeah, add the link like this: `<a href="#" class="change_link">Change</a>` (for example).

Comment: You can make it whatever you want, as long as the HTML and JS match up. For example, you can't make it `id="change_link"` in the HTML but make it `$(".change_link")` in the JS.

Comment: So how should I reference the link to the javascript?

Comment: With the example I gave, `$("a.change_link")`.

Comment: Yes, but isn't that javascript, don't I need a link in the html?

Comment: In the HTML is what I put above. `<a href="#" class="change_link">Change</a>`.

Comment: I tied everything together, but it doesn't seem to be working. And also the script you gave me doesn't allow me post anything else in the HTML file

Answer (score 0):

in `<source src="video.mp4" type="video.mp4" />` line type="video.mp4" is wrong you cant place this type of value here

here's is the some example of type : video/mp3, video/ogg, video/wbem.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are asking for, if you stick the video path in say the alt of the link, you can then reference it and stick that into the src of the video onclick with some simple jquery.

- [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgwJ6/1/)

**Modified html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Videos</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="VideosPage.css">
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
<video id="first_video" width="800" height="450" controls="controls" style="margin-left:380px;  padding:10px; border:1px solid black;">
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp3" />
</video>
 <br />
 <a alt="video2.mp4" id="other"> Other Video </a>​
```

**Some jquery:**

```
$('#other').click( function() { 
$('#first_video').children('source').attr('src',$(this).attr('alt'))
});​
```